# Mutt : render html within mutt

Tags: mutt, html, w3m

I want to render html within mutt but I haven't succeed configuring it yet.

I want to use w3m so my *.mailcap* looks like :

```
text/html; "$BROWSER" %s &; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"; needsterminal;
text/html; w3m -I %{charset} -T text/hmtl; copiousoutput;
```

And for the rendering in mutt I have added :

```
auto_view text/html
alternative_order text/plain text/enriched text/html
```

This is what I looks like when I open a *text/html* document (I press `v` and then `return` to the *text/html*)

```
[-- Autoview using w3m -I 'utf-8' -T text/hmtl --]
<html><head></head><body><!-- content: html tiny_mce -->
<p>Bonjour a tous,</p>
<p>Une page Didel pour le cours Analyse et Probabilites a ete cree.</p>
<p>Tous les etudiants qui suivent ce cours sont invites a y s'insrcire.</p>
<p>Les DMs vont etre mises en ligne sur ce site.</p>
<p>Cordialement,</p>
<p>Adina Ralea</p>

<div class="lnk_link_panel">
</div>
<br /><br />-- <br />Adina Giorgianna Ralea<br />Gestionnaire du cours L3
+Mathématiques-Informatique 2015-2016 (L3MI2014)<br /><br /><a
+href="http://didel.script.univ-paris-diderot.fr/">Diderot en ligne</a><br
+/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Administrateur: <a
+href="mailto:admin-didel@script.univ-paris-diderot.fr">Admin</a><br
+/></body></html>
```

We can see that autoview is using w3m, but why isn't it rendering ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-T` value you are passing to `w3m` has a typo. It should be `text/html` instead of `text/hmtl`:

```
text/html; w3m -I %{charset} -T text/html; copiousoutput;
```

Comment: Oh thank you ! This such a shame, I have asked many questions these days it was always some stupid errors... I apologize to the community.

Comment: On the contrary @NicolasScottoDiPerto, I needed this particular q/a to set mine up, first time :)